# FlaskForm had to reload select choices

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to Python and Flask. I am trying to use WTForm FlaskForm, and having problems with choices in SelectField. I am building my forms like this.

```
class FightForm(FlaskForm):
    fight_id = StringField('fight_id', render_kw={'readonly': True})
    fight_type_id = SelectField('fight_type_id', 
        choices=[(t.fight_type_id, t.type_name) for t in fight_type.query.all()], validate_choice=False, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

These choices appear to only load 1 time. If I go add a new `fight_type`, I have to stop the application and restart if for it to refresh.

Also, I found this answer, [flask wtforms selectfield choices not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515009/flask-wtforms-selectfield-choices-not-update), but FlaskForm does not trigger the `__init__` function this suggests.

I changed it temporarily to Form anyway and got an error saying fight_type_id does not belong to form (paraphrasing).

I would like for these to refresh every time I call the page.

Comment: Perhaps the extension [WTForms-SQLAlchemy](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/) with the [QuerySelectField](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/#wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField) will help you.

Comment: I can't figure out how to set that up. I tried installing WTForms-SQLAlchemy and importing QuerySelectField, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the [WTForms-SQLAlchemy](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/) extension.
The [QuerySelectField](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/#wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField) dynamically loads all database entries based on a submitted database query. A column can be defined for the label of an entry. When the form is submitted, the selected object is automatically queried from the database and is returned by the field.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'your secret here'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

class FightType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Fight(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fight_type.id'))
    type = db.relationship('FightType', backref='fights')

class FightForm(FlaskForm):
    type = QuerySelectField(
        get_label='name',
        query_factory=lambda: FightType.query.all(),
        validators=[InputRequired()]
    )

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    types = [FightType(name=f'type-{i}') for i in range(10)]
    db.session.add_all(types)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    fights = Fight.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/fight/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fight_create():
    form = FightForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        fight = Fight()
        form.populate_obj(fight)
        db.session.add(fight)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('create.html', **locals())

@app.route('/fight/<int:fight_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fight_update(fight_id):
    fight = Fight.query.get_or_404(fight_id)
    form = FightForm(request.form, obj=fight)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(fight)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('update.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (templated/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('fight_create') }}">New</a>
    <ul>
      {% for f in fights -%}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('fight_update', fight_id=f.id) }}">
          {{ f.id }} - {{ f.type.name }}
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (templates/create.html, templates/update.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fight</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      {{ form.type.label }} {{ form.type() }}
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solved the issue I described but created a new issue. Now, when I reopen the form to edit the previous data, it does not select the previously selected value.

Comment: I have completed or changed my example. If I understand you correctly, the cause lies in the naming of the form fields and columns of the database model. These must match.