# WTForms turns choices into strings

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to dynamically create WTForm SelectField entries from a SQLAlchemy DB as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619945/4207752) but it seems like it does `repr()` or `str()` on the first part of each choice tuple which should be the `User` object. I did just find out about `QuerySelectField` but `wtforms.ext.*` packages have been deprecated.

```
class ChangeAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Queries user database and sets user choices
        super(ChangeAccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user.choices = [(i, i.username) for i in User.query.all()]

    user = SelectField('Gebruiker', validators=[Optional()])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need the entire User object in your rendered template? Normally you can use the user.id (as in the answer you linked)  field and use that value to  query your database after the form is posted.

Comment: @Maarten not really, it's just more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wtforms docs:

```
class wtforms.fields.SelectField(default field arguments, choices=[], 
    coerce=unicode, option_widget=None)

"""        
Select fields keep a choices property which is a sequence of (value, 
label) pairs. The value portion can be any type in theory, but as form 
data is sent by the browser as strings, you will need to provide a 
function which can coerce the string representation back to a 
comparable object.
"""
```

So the traditional method of using user.id is, a more future proof way of maintaining correct object coercion back to user if the User model were updated without the **repr** string being correctly amended, but 'id' will always be available as the primary key.