# Flask-SQLAlchemy @staticmethod delay

Tags: python, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've got a class in my `models.py` with this static method in it:

```
...
@staticmethod
def get_past_jobs():
    return Job.query.filter(Job.date < datetime.datetime.utcnow()).all()
...
```

This goes through the (irrelevant) `past_jobs_pretty()` formatting function which is used when constructing the form (WTForms):

```
...
job = SelectField('Past Job', choices=past_jobs_pretty(), validators=[DataRequired()])
...
```

The issue is this: when updating `Job.date` (through an SQLite browser), changes are not reflected in `SelectField` until I restart the development server.

**Theory:** I'm guessing this is due to `@staticmethod` getting the rows immediately when the server starts. Subsequent calls to `get_past_jobs()` would return the same rows due to the nature of static methods.

If this is correct, what's the alternative? I have tried using `@classmethod` but to no avail — same result.

Looking forward to some help.

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619945/3273967) answer and added the following to the form in question:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FeedbackForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.job.choices = past_jobs_pretty()
```